# Google Kubernetes Engine Stackdriver logging/monitoring is gone at gke version 1.15

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I'm using GKE for more than year and i never had any problems with stackdriver logging/monitoring. But when i created new cluster with version **1.15.9-gke.26** i don't see any logs in stackdriver (neither metrics). It also didn't work with **new** cluster with version 1.14. Although it works for older cluster which was updated to version 1.14 from 1.13.

Some settings:
gke version = 1.15.9-gke.26
Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring = System and workload logging and monitoring
VPC-native (alias IP) = Enabled
Workload Identity = Disabled

Weird things:
Following daemon sets have 0/0 pods (DaemonSet has no nodes selected):
- metadata-proxy-v0.1
- nvidia-gpu-device-plugin (doesn't sound useful)

I'm not sure how exactly stackdriver works and how to debug it... I will appreciate any tips

Deployments and daemonsets currently running at cluster:

```
kubectl get daemonsets,deployments --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                                                              AGE
kube-system   daemonset.extensions/fluentd-gcp-v3.1.1         3         3         3       3            3           beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux       16h
kube-system   daemonset.extensions/metadata-proxy-v0.1        0         0         0       0            0           beta.kubernetes.io/metadata-proxy-ready=true,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   16h
kube-system   daemonset.extensions/nvidia-gpu-device-plugin   0         0         0       0            0           <none>                                                                     16h
kube-system   daemonset.extensions/prometheus-to-sd           3         3         3       3            3           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux                                                16h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deployment.extensions/event-exporter-v0.3.0                      1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/fluentd-gcp-scaler                         1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/heapster-gke                               1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/kube-dns                                   2/2     2            2           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/kube-dns-autoscaler                        1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/l7-default-backend                         1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/metrics-server-v0.3.3                      1/1     1            1           16h
kube-system   deployment.extensions/stackdriver-metadata-agent-cluster-level   1/1     1            1           16h
```

Comment: I created a new GKE cluster with the `1.15.9-gke.26` version as yours and I can see the logs in `Metrics explorer`. Could you tell which metric did you try to use to determine if it's working? Can you try go to `Monitoring -> Metrics Explorer` and check the metric of: `kubernetes.io/node/memory/allocatable_utilization` with the filter `cluster-name`?

Comment: First of all - thanks for help :)
Unfortunately i see only "No data is available for the selected time frame.".
Also i was using stackdriver only for logs, so i was using logs viewer and couldn't find any logs.
Maybe it's because of some google's api permissions problem? It's separate project (comparing to the one for which it works). Once upon a time i had a problem with that project caused by terraform - it disabled some apis and i had to enable them manually - but it doesn't look like it's the case.

Comment: Please check the following: 1. Is logging enabled in the cluster? 2. Does access scopes allow logging? 3. Have you deployed this cluster with a default service account? 4. Are there any logging exclusions? 5. Check if logs are generated with `kubectl logs POD_NAME`. 6. How are you querying the logs? What exactly is missing in Stackdriver?

Comment: Our cluster also faced the same issue. The problem here is as of GKE version 1.14. they have chaged the default logging system. New logging system is called Kubernetes Engine Monitoring. You can read all about it https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine#select

Comment: You have to manually update your logging system, if you want to change it the previous one

Answer (score 1):

per documentation, and as @Darshan Naik mentioned:

> If you are using Legacy Logging and Monitoring, then you must switch to Kubernetes Engine Monitoring before support for Legacy Logging and Monitoring is removed. Legacy Logging and Monitoring will no longer be supported as of GKE 1.15.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine#select